# Deriving the temporal solution for the time dependent Schrödinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I'm having trouble deriving the following. Let $\theta_n (t)$ represent the trial solution for the TDSE as a function of time produced from a separation of variables.

Using the separation of variables method to solving the TDSE, somewhere along the line you get (as one of the final steps):

$$i\hbar \frac{d\theta_n (t)}{dt} = E_n \theta_n (t)$$

$$\implies \frac{d\theta_n (t)}{dt} = \frac{E_n}{i\hbar} \theta_n (t)$$

Here, I'm having trouble showing the solution $\theta_n (t) = 
e^{-iE_n t/h}$. By inspection, the answer should be $e^{\frac{E_nt}{i\hbar}}$. I either solved this incorrectly, or I have the wrong differential equation. However, this seems to agree with my lecture notes, and [here](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SchroedingerEquation.html), to my knowledge at least. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Those two are the same thing, because $\frac{1}{i} = -i$, which you can easily prove by multiplying either side by $\frac{i}{i}$

Comment: O-oh. Yeah. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks!